# Thunderbird: improper command pipelining

Tags: thunderbird

I have my own mail server running on a remote machine (Ubuntu, Postfix, Dovecot).

At home I have an old iMac (OS = macOS Catalina) and I also have a new multiboot machine with the operating systems Windows, Linux (Ubuntu) and macOS (Catalina) (i.e. a multiboot Hackintosh). Both machines live in the same local network. So, when they communicate with the world "outside" (like with my mail server) they share the same IP address.

I didn't try to set up Thunderbird under windows, but Thunderbird 68 is working without any problems on:

- old "real" iMac with Catalina
- new multiboot machine when switched to Linux (Ubuntu).

I have troubles to get Thunderbird running on the iMac-section of my multiboot machine. When I try to setup Thunderbird 68, in its first try to find settings for the connection it display a warning complaining that there is no encryption for the inbox server (German message: IMAP  Posteingangs-Server: Keine Verschlüsselung). This is wrong. There is an encryption. This message did not appear when I was setting up Thunderbird 68 on Linux.

But Thunderbird anyway did guess wrong settings (it always does, on every machine). This is no problem, I just have to correct the settings manually. But when they are correct (STARTTLS, normal Password for In and Out), and when I then click test again ("erneut testen") it reports on my hackintosh, that it could not find settings for my E-Mail account.

I tried the same game with an older version of thunderbird: Thunderbird 60. With this version I get the message, that the password is wrong, which is incorrect. I used the same password as on my "real" iMac and under Linux.

---

So, I looked into the log file of my mail server.

I do not get any error logs when I use Thunderbird on my old "real" iMac (Catalina), and I also don't get error logs when I use Thunderbird under Ubuntu on my new multiboot machine.

But when I try to setup Thunderbird on the macOS section of my multiboot machine (version 60 as well as version 68), I get this log message:

```
Nov  6 18:54:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[24041]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from improper command pipelining after EHLO from <...>: QUIT\r\n
Nov  6 18:54:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[24041]: disconnect from <...> ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
...
Nov  6 18:54:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[24041]: connect from <...>
Nov  6 18:54:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[24047]: lost connection after CONNECT from <...>
```

I intentionally use settings in my postfix config file to refuse smtp connections which send pipelined commands although my server doesn't allow pipelining. I do not want to change these settings, because I think it keeps off many spam spreaders, and because they work for more than 15 years. I never had troubles with this settings, and also my local e-mail clients (on Windows, Linux, macOS, iOS and Android) never had any troubles with these settings.

---

I have no idea why Thunderbird 68 on one iMac with Catalina is behaving different than Thunderbird 68 on a different iMac with Catalina in the same local network while Thunderbird 68 works perfect on the same machine when running under a different OS.

Just to make it clear: macOS Catalina on my multiboot machine is working perfect. Everything is fine, except Thunderbird. And also Thunderbird can communicate with my remote mail server. So it can't be a problem of a local firewall.

It also can't be a problem of my mail server, since it cooperates perfectly with other clients in the same network.

I think the problem is, that Thunderbird on one Catalina-machine uses pipelined commands while it doesn't on the other Catalina-machine, and it also doesn't under Linux. But I don't know why, and I don't know how I can fix it.

**Can you help?**

---

### ADDENDUM (reaction to a comment):

I copied the whole Thunderbird directory from my genuine Mac to my Hackintosh and then started Thunderbird on my Hackintosh. It did display any error messages when I started it, but it displayed all emails in all my accounts. The message that says that the Server had quit the connection and that either the server has quit or that there are network problems.

The logfile on my server shows 11 lines with this message:

Nov 16 18:36:44 mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=(my IP), lip=(sever's IP), TLS, session=<(a session ID)>

I then tried to send a test-mail from one of my accounts to another account (all in the same domain, on the same server)

I've got a message that says, that the message was sent, but it could not be stored in the sent-folder.

I also can't see this new e-mail in the receivers mailbox on my hackintosh. But I can see it when I use my genuine iMac.

On my genuine iMac I sent an answer, and it immediately appeared in the mailbox on my genuine iMac, but I can't see it on my hackintosh.

The logfile on my server displays similar entries for both sendings (from Hackintosh and from genuine iMac) for postfix.

So now it looks as if SMTP would work, but IMAP seems to have an authentication problem.

btw:

1. I installed Thunderbird also on the Windows section of the same multiboot machine, and it works without any problems there. (As said before: Thunderbird also works fine unter Linux on the same machine)
2. I added a second user on macOS and tried to setup a thunderbird account for this user, and I run into the same problems as for the first user.

Comment: Have you tried to just copying over the working Thunderbird profile from your genuine Mac to your Hackintosh?

Comment: [*Are “Hackintosh” questions allowed?*](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1471/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I think the fact, that one of the operating systems is a Hackintosh is not the reason for the problem. I think it is a problem of settings of thunderbird.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know your question may get closed.

Comment: I would investigate further by using *tcpdump* on the server to capture and *WireShark* to analyze and compare IMAP sessions initiated by the genuine iMac and the Hackintosh.

Comment: I switched to the MUA evolution. That was able to connect.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason for this problem and could solve it:

It was AVAST ANTIVIRUS. I didn't want to install Avast. It came together with some other software that I installed, and I didn't notice that I had to deselect it during the installation process.

Avast Antivirus caused the problems with thunderbird on my Mac. This is not how Antivirus software should behave.

It was really hard to find a way to uninstall avast antivirus form macOS, only the Mac Cleaner from iMyMac could do the job.

After I removed Avast from my computer and rebooted, Thunderbird worked without any problems.

Comment: I didn't want to post this inside my "answer" to my own question, but the way how Avast behaved classifies it as malware: 1. It tricked me to install it although I didn't want it. 2. It caused a denial of service on my computer, and 3. it was extremely hard to uninstall. I knew this aggressive and destructive behavior only from *Mac Cleaner* which many people also classify as malware.